# create a maven project in to a single view

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build

I am trying to import a maven project into eclipse. Please find the structure of my project

```
mainproject
     - module1
          - pom.xml
          - src
          - resouces
     - compile
           - pom.xml
     - src
           - pom.xml
```

After importing i found 3 projects in my eclipse. I think for each pom.xml it creates separate project. I need to import around 6 project which has the above breakdown structure. Is it possible to import into a single project in which it should contain my modules so that i can manage it properly. 
ie) all the submodules should comes under one mainproject and the internal structure should be maintained so that i can view only the projects imported not for each pom.xml a project.

Comment: I'm not sure whether i understood correctly why don't you try maven multi module project structure check this link: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/reactor.html

Comment: @soorapadman Still it creates individual projects

Answer (score 0):

Your Maven project structure is not correct.

Projects with sub-modules must have the structure like below:

```
mainprojet
   - pom.xml (This is the main pom which declare the other submodules)
   - submodule1
        - pom.xml
        - src/main/java (your Java code)
        - src/main/resources (Your resources files, conf files, etc.)
        - src/test/java (Your Java Unit-test code)
        - src/test/resources (Your resources files for tests)
   - submoduleN
        - pom.xml
        - src/main/java (your Java code)
        - src/main/resources (Your resources files, conf files, etc.)
        - src/test/java (Your Java Unit-test code)
        - src/test/resources (Your resources files for tests)
    - etc...
```

The parent pom.xml (in mainprojet folder), must contains all sub-modules:

```
<modules>
    <module>submodule1</module>
    <module>submoduleN</module>

</modules>
```

And All pom.xml of sub-modules must declare the parent pom like that:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>YourGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>Your artifactId/artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

You can also look into the Maven Multi-modules documentation:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/reactor.html

Comment: yes you are right. But importing it shows as individual projects. difficult to manage

Comment: Adding to your structure while importing it shows 3 projects. I want that to be one project with the same structure and same context. Is there any custom plugin available  for this?

Comment: I don't think you have so much possibilities when using a multi modules Maven project. In Eclipse, you can also create a "Working Set" of the modules to see them in one view.  (but there are still independant maven modules.)
http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcworkset.htm

Comment: I've tried. as you said it is not  much flexible. Just creating a folder with names of submodules and still creating individual projects